# Password Hashing Not Working For MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have been on here all day and looked at all of the answered wuestions and also looked at tutorials online regarding password hashing. It seems as though I am doing it right and it hashes the password in the database but when I go to login it tells me that the password is incorrect. Here is the script, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Login.PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
//escapes special characters in a string
$username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
//Checking is user existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$hash = $row['password'];
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    // Redirect user to index.php
    $position = $row['position'];
    if ( $position == "freelancer" ){
    header("Location: ../freelancer/index.php");
    }
    elseif ($position == "employer"){
    header("Location: ../employer/index.php");
    }
}
else{
echo "<div class='form'>
<h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
".$hash." " .$password. "
<br />Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a>
</div>";
```

Register.PHP (Piece of Code that Hashes the Password)

```
   //BEGINNING CODE HERE
$password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
$hashPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql_u = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$sql_e = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$res_u = mysqli_query($con, $sql_u);
$res_e = mysqli_query($con, $sql_e);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res_u) > 0) {
$name_error = "Sorry... username already taken";
}
else if(mysqli_num_rows($res_e) > 0){
$email_error = "Sorry... email already taken";
}
else{
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$hashPassword')";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);
mkdir("../profilePics/" . $username);
echo 'You Have Registered Successfully!<br>
To Login Go To <a href="login.php">Our Login Page</a>
';
exit();
}
}
?>
```

I know there may be more things wrong with this code But I am only interested in getting a basic understanding of password hashing.

Comment: Common mistake is the password column's length is too short. It needs to be 60 characters.

Comment: You stored your hashed password in `hash` field. You better change - `$hash = $row['password'];` - to - `$hash = $row['hash`'];`

Comment: It could be that the length of your password field is not long enough and the data gets truncated.

Comment: Secondly, what is the `password` column and what is the `hash` column? Are you storing the password in plain text too?

Comment: Thirdly, seeing as you are using `mysqli_*`, why not make use of prepared statements.

Comment: No its not the hash field. Its the password field. Hash is something totally different

Comment: My password field for mySQL is 256

Comment: Then that's the problem `$hashPassword` is stored in `hash` while you're getting the password in `password` column

Comment: Could it be the `mysqli_real_escape_string` on `$password`?

Comment: What is the difference between `$hash = $row['password'];` and
`$hashing = $row['password'];`?

Comment: oddly enough though all the hashes are coming out to 32 characters

Comment: No im storing the hashed password in password and getting the password from the appropriate password field. Hash is for emails. They are also 2 different scripts, one for logging in and one for registration. I know this may be confusing but just trust me when I say ignore hash. When I echo out the results of $password and the password entered it gives me the password the user entered in plain text and the hashed password in the database

Comment: @JosephAlvini if I understand your last comment correctly, you *are* storing the password in plain text too, in which case, you are undoing the work that your hash is supposed to be doing. Please, don't store passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
```

You password is now escaped and it certainly won't match the hash.
Better remove this line and look for a better way to ensure the string is safe.

What does escape means?
if your password contains "
it will turns into \"

FYI 
[Should I mysql_real_escape_string the password entered in the registration form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274242/should-i-mysql-real-escape-string-the-password-entered-in-the-registration-form)

Comment: *cough* The better way would be prepared statements. *cough*

Comment: as far as I know, the password verify did manage to deal with security of the string passing in.

Comment: Exactly What it was. And script147 was partially correct also. Thanks Guys, I am really trying to learn how to build around security rather than just building carelessly

Comment: @JosephAlvini FYI: I mentioned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575571/password-hashing-not-working-for-mysql/50575733?noredirect=1#comment88160363_50575571) in the comments 27 minutes earlier... Secondly, if you used prepared statements you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: @Script147 Sorry about that. I genuinely missed it. Also as far as the prepared statements go I am going to look into that. I am new to PHP so I am learning from the ground up.

Comment: @JosephAlvini you must have also missed my username (`Script47`)? :P

Comment: @Script47 OOPS. Im sorry I am rushing around and real tired. I had a long day. Thanks though man, I do appreciate the help. I have been diving into PHP Dev and love it and since you told me about Prepared statments I have been on w3schools looking at it and implementing it into my own code. Hey BTW, whats your stance on OOP? I read good and bad stuff about it and wanna know if its worth the effort. None the less people seem to be very opinionated about it.